# Why does Python return -1 for string.rfind(last character of string, 0, len(string) - 1)?

Tags: python, string

For Python `str.rfind(sub[, start[, end]])` method, I think these are the default values for the start and end parameters:
start = 0
end = the index of the last character of the string, which is equivalent to the length of the string minus 1.

However, Python returns different results for lines 3 and 4 below. For line 3, Python returns 23 which is what I expect. For line 4, Python returns 14 when I expect a return value of 23.

Could you please help explain why lines 3 and 4 do not return the same value of 23?

```py
a = "Autumn's the mellow time"
print("Length of a:", len(a))
print(a.rfind("e"))
print(a.rfind("e", 0, len(a) - 1))
```

Output:

```
Length of a: 24
23
14
```

Comment: Ranges are generally end-exclusive in Python, this is no different - _"Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation."_

Comment: i should add that it would be helpful if the documentation was clearer and specified `start is incluside`, `end is exclusive` as opposed (or in addition) to `slice notation`... so for this reason, i have upvoted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the third argument `__end` is **exclusive**.

So basically, you dont need to subtract 1.

This is quite common in lists (range) in python and particularly in `slice` notation.

So this works:

```py
a = "Autumn's the mellow time"
print("Length of a:", len(a))
print(a.rfind("e"))
print(a.rfind("e", 0, len(a)))
```

which will give what you are seeking:

```
Length of a: 24
23
23
```

So, it was (conveniently) easier than you anticipated.